# Upgrading infragistics controls from one version to another version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, infragistics

I had worked in the Kendo UI platform. Now I got a new task, like I have to upgrade Infragistics controls from version 7.1 to 11. What all are the procedures I have to follow in order to upgrade, can any body guide me? Is there any tool available to automatically upgrade? I have installed NetAdvantage 7.1 and 11.1 and by mistake, 13.1, will this produce any issues? I have installed three versions of the controls into Visual Studio tool explorer. Do I need to uninstall 13.1?
When I was working for Kendo UI there was only one version, so I don't need to worry about anything, but now things are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each version of Infragistics can be independent of each other, so that is not a problem. To upgrade from one version to another, run the **version utility** for the Infragistics version you want to upgrade to, and select your website. It will upgrade it for you. If there is any problem, then an error log will tell where to look.

Comment: But we cant upgrade from version 2011 to 2013 rite by using version utility, we have to do manually??

Comment: You should be able to using the 2013 copy of Version Utility. If it doesn't work it is usually something it doesn't like and the log will tell you where to look to fix, and then try it again. If not, then you can manually update your web.config file. Version utility is also better since occasionally Infragistics will deprecate  some things and the utility will tell you that as well. Also, make sure the ig_res and ig_common directory, if used, has the correct version of the infragistics files for consistency, though the infragistics install should take care of all that for you.